# Docker on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, docker

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (ubuntu-16.04.1-server-amd64.iso) on VirtualBox. Checking Docker's status with:

`service docker.io status` I get:

```
o docker.io.service
Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
```

If I try and install it with:

```
apt-get install -y docker.io
```

I get `docker.io is already the newest version`.

If I then try and start it with:

```
sudo service docker.io start
```

I get:

```
Failed to start docker.io.service: Unit docker.io.service not found
```

What am I missing?

Comment: The [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntulinux/) are pretty clear but the easiest way to install or upgrade is `curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh`. The script is maintained by the Docker guys and kept up to date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The service name is `docker`, not `docker.io`.

Comment: Yes, that works. So confusing - sometimes it's referred to as `docker.io` and sometimes as `docker`.